# Oracle POSIX dosent match Regular Expression

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, posix, regexp-replace

I am trying to replace newlines with regex. I got two databases Oralce and MySQL. The SQL statment works fine on MySQL but not with Oralce.

This is my example text:

```
<ul>
<li>Was soll erreicht worden sein, wenn man das Projekt durchgeführt hat?</li>
</ul>
Formulieren Sie immer konkret.
<ul>
<li><strong><span style=\"color: #800000;\">Wirtschaftliche Ziele</span></strong> (z. B.: Umsatzsteigerung im betroffenen Produktbereich: 20% im 3. Quartal des ersten Geschäftsjahres)</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

The goal is to place an `</ul><br/>` after every `</li></ul>` where the following character is a newline NOT followed my the character `<`.

Working solution in MySQL :

```
SELECT *,
REGEXP_REPLACE(DeInfo, '(<\/ul>)(\r?\n)(?=[^<])', '</ul><br/>') as newDeInfo,
DeInfo
FROM txttrans
```

Not working Oralce statement:

```
SELECT id, deinfo, FIRMID,
REGEXP_REPLACE(DeInfo, '(<\/ul>)(\r ? \n)(?=[^<])', '</ul><br/>', 1, 0, 'i') as TEST
FROM txttrans
```

Comment: Oracle does not support look-ahead and you've mentioned posix but you are not actually using [posix character classes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm) (you're using PERL style character classes)

Comment: Assertions aren't [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). The syntax Oracle supports is [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Oracle-Regular-Expression-Support.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Alex,

the working solution:

```
SELECT id, deinfo, FIRMID,
REGEXP_REPLACE(DeInfo, '(</ul>)([[:space:]][^<])([^<br />]{0})', '</ul><br/>\2', 1, 0, 'i') as TEST
FROM txttrans;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Oracle does not support look ahead you can try use a normal capture group instead and use it in the replacement.

```
SELECT id, deinfo, FIRMID,
REGEXP_REPLACE(DeInfo, '(<\/ul>)(\r ? \n)([^<])', '</ul><br/>\3', 1, 0, 'i') as TEST
FROM txttrans
```

Comment: Why did you add ```3$``` in the replace parameter?

Comment: It was a typo, you need to use \3, not $3. The idea is the following: you cannot use a lookahead, so you must actually capture the next symbol, and then use it in the replacement string. For example, in the string `</ul>\nSome text`  the first matching group will capture `</ul>`, the second will capture the new line `\n` and the 3rd group will capture a letter `S`. So we replace the whole match `</ul>\nS` with `</ul><br/>S`, which gives `</ul><br/>Some text`

Comment: That make sense. I try too adapt your idea, but it allways add ```</ul><br/>\3```. That is my solution:  ```SELECT id, deinfo, FIRMID,
REGEXP_REPLACE(DeInfo, '</ul>[[:space:]][^<][^<br />]{0}', '</ul><br/>\3', 1, 0, 'i') as TEST
FROM txttrans;```